# Combinar 2 gráficos highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Estoy intentando crear un gráfico que combine el gráfico 'bubble' y 'line' de higcharts, pero no llega a dibujarse.

```js
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'xy',
                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        title: {
                            text: 'Temperature'
                        }
                    }, {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Rainfall'
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }],
                
                    series: [{
                        type: 'line',
                        data: [[1, 29.9], [2, 71.5], [3, 106.4], [5, 129.2]],
                        name: 'Temperature'
                    }, {
                        type: 'bubble',
                        data: [[1, 81, 63],
                            [2, 5, 89],
                            [3, 50, 73]],
                        name: 'Rainfall'
                    }]
                });
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body>
            <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

No sé que es lo que estoy haciendo mal o si es que no es posible. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```js
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'xy',
                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        title: {
                            text: 'Temperature'
                        }
                    }, {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Rainfall'
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }],
                
                    series: [{
                        type: 'line',
                        data: [[1, 29.9], [2, 71.5], [3, 106.4], [5, 129.2]],
                        name: 'Temperature'
                    }],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    id: 'Temperature',
                        type: 'bubble',
                        data: [[1, 81, 63],
                            [2, 5, 89],
                            [3, 50, 73]],
                        name: 'Rainfall'
                    }
                });
```

Puedes hacer uso del drilldown y definir en tu primer nivel que seria la linea y luego en el segundo nivel defines las n tipos de gráficos que quieras mostrar. Si lograr hacer lo funcionar me dices, yo igual estoy atascado para mostrar la serie del segundo nivel.

Answer (score 0):

Al final conseguí combinarlo.
Mira este ejemplo a ver si te sirve http://jsfiddle.net/47a0wL5h/

Te recomiendo utilizar el foro de Highcharts(https://forum.highcharts.com/), tiene muchos ejemplos y soluciones a problemas que me he ido encontrado.

Saludos